# MySQL throws errors while adding datetime less than 1970

Tags: mysql

I noticed than MySQL throws an error if I try to add datetime with value less than 1970 year (for instance, 1969-01-01 00:00:01). The reason for this is that timestamp in MySQL starts only from 1970. But, in my testing server, I am able to add datetimes less than 1970. On production server - not. Why so? I suppose that MySQL was configured differently on production and testing servers using different sql modes. But I couldn't find which mode is responsible for such a behaviour.

Comment: Are they the same MySQL version?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`? I can use that date for a `DATETIME`, but not `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: WHen I try to use that date with a timestamp I get a warning "Out of range value for column 'd2' at row 1". You may have a setting that's turning the warning into a fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently have strict SQL mode enabled on the production server, but not the testing server. The documentation on [Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html) says:

> When MySQL stores a value in a numeric column that is outside the
> permissible range of the column data type, the result depends on the
> SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, MySQL rejects the out-of-range value
>   with an error, and the insert fails, in accordance with the SQL
>   standard.
> - If no restrictive modes are enabled, MySQL clips the value to the
>   appropriate endpoint of the column data type range and stores the
>   resulting value instead.

When I try to store that date into a `TIMESTAMP` column on a server without strict SQL mode, I get a warning:

> Out of range value for column 'd2' at row 1

and it stores `0000-00-00 00:00:00` instead.